# Como pasar variable de javascript a twig?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, symfony2, twig

El siguiente código es para que se me cargue en la página un `CSS` u otro en dependencia del tema elegido. Este código funciona perfectamente en la página `HTML` pura, pero cuando lo intento llevar a mi aplicación `Symfony` no hallo la forma de pasarle al `JS` la ruta del `CSS` con `Twig`.

```js
var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
            {};
            var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
            if (themeName)
            {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app-' + themeName + '.css">');
            }
            else
            {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app.css">');
            }
```

Es decir yo quiero que en el `href` de la función `document.write` se me cargue (por ejemplo) lo que con `Twig` sería esto:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-red.css') }} "rel="stylesheet" >
```

Donde `app-` es fijo y lo que varía es la palabra `red` según el valor de la variable `themeName`

Para esto he intentado lo siguiente pero no me funciona de esta forma:

```
 <script>
        var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
        {};
        var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
        if (themeName)
        {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app-' ~ themeName ~ '.css') }} ">');
        }
        else
        {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }} ">');
        }
    </script>
```

Esto me lanza este error:

> Variable "themeName" does not exist in ::base.html.twig at line 1188

Luego intenté hacer esto:

```
<script>
        var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
        {};
        var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
        if (themeName)
        {
            var cadenacss = "asset('bundles/activos/css/app-')" ~ themeName ~ '.css">';
                {% set cadena=cadenacss %} 
                   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{ cadena }}">');
        }
        else
        {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }} ">');
        }
    </script>
```

Y tampoco funciona, me muestra el siguiente error:

> Variable "cadenacss" does not exist in ::base.html.twig at line 1189

No encuentro la forma de hacer esto pasando la variable de JS a Twig. Primero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de pasar variables de JS a Twig, pero si no sepuede hacer, entonces quisiera saber alguna otra forma de que pueda resolver esto.

Comment: Bueno he googleado un poco y según he entendido creo que lo que debo hacer es pasar dicha variable js (themeName) por ajax para un controlador y de ahí devolverla a la vista a través de twig para poder construir el href con twig. Esa puede ser una forma. Si me pudieran ayudar con esto se los agradeceré, ya que no tengo experiencia con ajax como para hacer esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debido a que conozco todos los posibles valores que puede tomar la variable `themeName`, me di cuenta que podía resolver esto de una manera muy sencilla. Aunque con esta variante no estoy pasando ninguna variable desde `Javascript` a `Twig`, por lo que no estoy dando respuesta al título de la pregunta, pero sí le doy solución a la problemática planteada.

```
<script>
   var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
   {};
   var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
   if (themeName)
   {
            if (themeName === "blue")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-orange.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "custom")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "green")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-green.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "orange")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-orange.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "purple")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-purple.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "red")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-red.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
            if (themeName === "seagreen")
                {
                     document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-seagreen.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
  }
    else{
         document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
  }

  </script>
```

Con ésto pude solucionarlo aunque sigo sin saber como se podría hacer de la otra forma, o sea pasando la variable `themeName` al `Controller` y luego devolverla al `Twig`; para el caso en que no conozca los posibles valores que puede tomar esta variable.

Answer (score 2):

Pudieras almacenar la variable que te da el tema en una cookie, desde el controller lo puedes hacer, y luego con JavaScript verificas que exista la cookie y obtienes el valor almacenado; en caso de no existir pues estableces un tema por defecto.

---

#### Ejemplo práctico de implementación

En el controller de entrada a la aplicación:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
   $miVariable = algo de la base de datos por ejemplo
   $vista = $this->renderView('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('varible'=$mivaraible));

   $response = new Response($vista);

    $cookieFromRequest = $request->cookies;
    if (!$cookiesFromRequest->has('myAppTheme'))
    {
        $cookieTheme = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie("myApptheme", "defaultTheme");
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookieTheme);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Y en el JavaScript (adaptándolo al ejercicio actual y para agilizar) usando el pluggin jQuery.cookie, intenta obtener la cookie con nombre myApptheme:

```js
var theme = $.cookie('myApptheme');
if(theme !== null)
{
   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app-' + theme + '.css">');
}
else
{
   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app.css">');
}
```

---

Considero que otra solución sería almacenar el tema seleccionado por el usuario en la base de datos (si emplearas base de datos) y, desde el JavaScript, obtener ese valor vía AJAX (puedes auxiliarte del bundle `FOSJsRoutingBundle` para llamar al controller desde el JavaScript).

Y una tercera solución, pues hacerlo todo desde el javascript: intentar obtener una cookie que contenga el tema, si no existe crearla con el tema por defecto y la consiguiente etiqueta de estilo para el mismo.
Y digamos que cuando el usuario selecciona un tema de los propuestos, escribir su nombre en la cookie para utilizarla en otras peticiones.

Answer (score 1):

Debes colocar directamente en tu template:

```
 <link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-' ~ themeName ~ '.css') }} "rel="stylesheet" >
```

Y en tu controller debes pasar ese parametro

```
return $this->render('index.html.twig', array(
    'template' => $template
));
```

Para este caso no necesitas AJAX, solo necesitas ajax si quieres hacer lo inverso, pasar parametros de Javascript a Symphony

Comment: Creo que no entendiste bien mi pregunta, respecto a lo que me escribiste: "solo necesitas ajax si quieres hacer lo inverso, pasar parametros de Javascript a Symphony". Eso precisamente es lo que necesito. Me puedes dar un ejemplo de como hacer esto con ajax?